# Документирование форматов информационного обмена по средствам парсинга xsd. Ищу исходники

Tags: c#, winforms, xmlparser, xsd

Пишу софт, который документирует (описывает) формат обмена данными для SOAP сервисов.

У меня есть xsd с описанием формата обмена. 
Мне необходимо с помощью SOM обойти все элементы и построить в ms word таблицы с описанием каждого элемента. На каждый комплексный элемент (точнее - тип элемента) создаётся своя таблица с описанием. 
В результате получается набор таблиц с описанием всех элементов.
Программа написана на 70%, но возникли вопросы с которыми я пока справиться не могу.

Суть проблемы: 
Большинство ответов про работу с xsd сводится к тому, как сгенерить нужный класс в нужном языке программирования, используя утилиту генерации классов. Мне это не подходит, т.к. формат может быть любой, следовательно и xsd может быть любой и заранее не известен.
Если гуглить в сторону документирования форматов информационного обмена, то чаще всего встречаешься с описанием утилит, для различных xml вьювиров и редакторов (Альтова и т.д.).

Сталкивались ли вы с исходниками подобных программ (желательно c#)? 
(поделитесь ссылкой, пожалуйста 8))

Comment: В гитхабе есть поиск. https://github.com/7digital/XsdToObject

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо вам за ссылку! Посмотрю обязательно!